# Setting the width of an image to its parent's parent's parent

Tags: html, css, width

I'm trying to make the width of this sample image to be 100% of the width of the purple background  "#container" div, even as the page is re-sized. It's structured this way for other reasons, that I don't think I can get around. It seems like it should be a simple solution, but I cant seem to find an answer.

The HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sample Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div class="media">
                <ul class="gallery" id="house1">
                    <li><img src="https://analogphotogs.files.wordpress.com/2011/05/lc-w_sample_01.jpg"></li>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 50vw;
    height: 50vw;
    background-color: purple;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
}

.gallery li img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear `ul`'s default margin and padding by setting it to 0, and changing the image width to `max-width: 100%`.

```
#container {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vw;
  background-color: purple;
}

ul{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

.gallery li img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: That's what my problem was! Thanks! I guess I missed one of those when I was trying to clear all the padding. It works exactly as I was hoping for now. :)

Answer (score 1):

For the `width: 100%` to take effect, the width of the parent element has to   defined beforehand. This is most likely not the case for your `<li>` element.

I believe your actual problem is that the padding on the `<ul>` element is preventing your image from taking up the entire width. Try adding `padding-left:0;` to it.

Comment: I changed the CSS to include:

Comment: .gallery li {
 width: 100%;
}

Comment: Still doesn't work, so do I try to make the image see the div as it's parent? jQuery?

Comment: It's the padding on the `<ul>` element.